# Django rest PageNumber Pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Pagination class of the django rest framework:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

# Create your views here.
class ResultSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Result.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResultSetSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

This class currently returns a dict with `'prev'` and `'next'` keys that contains a URL with the next page and prev page. What I would like to achieve is that the `'prev'` and `'next'` return just the page number instead of the whole URL.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `get_next_link` and `get_previous_link` of PageNumberPagination
Default is:

```
   def get_next_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_next():
            return None
        url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        page_number = self.page.next_page_number()
        return replace_query_param(url, self.page_query_param, page_number)

    def get_previous_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_previous():
            return None
        url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        page_number = self.page.previous_page_number()
        if page_number == 1:
            return remove_query_param(url, self.page_query_param)
        return replace_query_param(url, self.page_query_param, page_number)
```

You can override:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_next_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_next():
            return None
        page_number = self.page.next_page_number()
        return page_number

    def get_previous_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_previous():
            return None
        page_number = self.page.previous_page_number()
        return page_number
```

Comment: @itts how to rename the previous to prev ?? Key name

Comment: @giveJob To rename to previous override the function get_paginated_response like : ```def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('prev', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', data)
        ]))```